# Google Maps Geolocation API limited at 100 requests even with billing enabled?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-geolocation

Did Google changed recently "his terms" about the Google Maps APIs ??

My APIs were working fine and I had billing enabled even if I never was billed cause I never reached the free 2 500 requests / day allowed.

Now it seems that we are limited to 100 requests / day + 1 request/second/user... and I believe my app is not working fine anymore because of this (unless the API keys could have changed with Google's changes?!?).

Is there anyone who also has billing enabled and still is limited to 100 requests per day?
Or anyone knows how to get rid of this limits?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

[image: Geocoding Query Limit]

This is exactly what the Google Developer Console told me three minutes ago.